I'm having a lot of trouble differentiating formBuilder and formGroup
I'm studying a code in Angular and I have the following codes
cadastro.component.HTML
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-card class="shipping-card">
    <mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-title>Cadastro</mat-card-title>
</mat-card-header>
<mat-card-content>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Nome" formControlName="firstName">
        @if (addressForm.controls) {
        <mat-error>Nome é <strong>obrigatório</strong></mat-error>
        }
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
        @if (addressForm.controls['email'].hasError('required')) {
        <mat-error>Email é <strong>obrigatório</strong></mat-error>
        }
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-card>
</form>

cadastro.component.ts
export class CadastroComponent {
private fb = inject(FormBuilder);


 addressForm = this.fb.group({

 firstName: [null, Validators.required],
 email: [null, Validators.required]

 });

 }

Looking at this code, is the developer using formBuilder and formGroup together? is this possible?
In the cadastro.component.html file, What does the 'controls' method do? on the line where addressForm.controls is, I looked in the documentation and didn't find this 'controls' method anywhere

The developer is using both FormGroup and FormBuilder. I would recommend that you prompt ChatGPT or Claude and ask them to explain step-by-step what is going on in the code. You can ask them follow-up questions and slowly fill up any knowledge gaps. You might not have found controls explicitly in the documentation because they are not methods—they are properties of the FormGroup class.
